# Can only delete an object from the Realm it belongs to

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm

Im getting this error "**Can only delete an object from the Realm it belongs to**" every time I try to delete an object from realm on my tableview. Here is the relevant code:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
var checklists = [ChecklistDataModel]()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    checklists = []
    let getChecklists = realm.objects(ChecklistDataModel.self)

    for item in getChecklists{

        let newChecklist = ChecklistDataModel()
        newChecklist.name = item.name
        newChecklist.note = item.note

        checklists.append(newChecklist)
    }

    tableView.reloadData()

}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return checklists.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChecklistCell", for: indexPath) as! ListsTableViewCell

    cell.name.text = checklists[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        // Delete the row from the data source
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(checklists[indexPath.row])
        }

        //delete locally
        checklists.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

I know it is this part to be specific:

```
     // Delete the row from the data source
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(checklists[indexPath.row])
        }
```

Any ideas of what is going on?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are trying to delete copies of your Realm objects stored in a collection instead of your actual Realm objects stored in Realm.

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.delete(Realm.objects(ChecklistDataModel.self).filter("name=%@",checklists[indexPath.row].name))
}
```

Without the definition of CheklistDataModel, I am not sure if I got the NSPredicate right, but you should be able to figure it out from here.

Answer (score 1):

From the code snippets you shared, you appear to be creating new `ChecklistDataModel` objects but never adding them to any Realm. Then you attempt to delete these objects from your Realm in your `try! realm.write` block.

Simply instantiating an object does not mean it has been added to a Realm; until it is added to a Realm through a successful write transaction it behaves just like any other Swift instance. Only after you've added the object to a Realm can you successfully delete it from that same Realm.

Answer (score 0):

```
after delete last Object check fetch data in View   

  // fetched data
    func fetchData()  {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let entrys = realm.objects(Entry.self)
        // displying result ...
        if(!entrys.isEmpty){
            self.entries.removeAll()
            for n in entrys{
                self.entries.append(n)
            }
        }else{
            self.entries.removeAll()
            for n in entrys{
                self.entries.append(n)
            }
        }
    }
```