# Realm with Value Types deleting objects

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

i create protocol for realm object follow this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@gonzalezreal/using-realm-with-value-types-b69947741e8b

and i have:

```
public protocol Persistable {
associatedtype PropertyValue: PropertyValueType
associatedtype ManagedObject: RealmSwift.Object
associatedtype Query: QueryType

init(managedObject: ManagedObject)

func getManagedObject() -> ManagedObject 

}

 public typealias PropertyValuePair = (name: String, value: Any)

 public protocol PropertyValueType {
    var propertyValuePair: PropertyValuePair { get }
}

 public protocol QueryType {
    var predicate: NSPredicate? { get }
    var sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor] { get }
}
```

and I would like to create method like :

```
public func delete<T: Persistable>(_ value: T) {
    realm.delete(value) 
}
```

While trying

```
realm.delete(value.getManagedObject())
```

ill get error from realm 'Can only delete an object from the Realm it belongs to.'

for deleting objc using my protocol.

Comment: You are not using any instance of `Realm`?

Comment: func delete is in calss with instance of Realm, and instance's name is 'realm'

Comment: Did you add the object to a Realm first before trying to delete it? Was it the same Realm? There isn't anything mysterious about the error message; you don't show enough code for us to tell whether you're using Realm correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The way I addressed this was by making sure the object I was giving to the Realm to delete was just fetched directly from the Realm. It doesn't seem to like the mapped objects made by 'getManagedObject'.

See this question for more information: [Can only delete an object from the Realm it belongs to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860885/can-only-delete-an-object-from-the-realm-it-belongs-to#43865118)